# Converting matches from 8-bit 4 channels to 64-bit 1 channel in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, color-space

I have a `vector` of `Point2f` which have color space `CV_8UC4` and need to convert them to `CV_64F`, is the following code correct?

```
points1.convertTo(points1, CV_64F);
```

**More details:**

I am trying to use this function to calculate the essential matrix (rotation/translation) through the 5-point algorithm, instead of using the findFundamentalMath included in OpenCV, which is based on the 8-point algorithm:

https://github.com/prclibo/relative-pose-estimation/blob/master/five-point-nister/five-point.cpp#L69

As you can see it first converts the image to `CV_64F`. My input image is a `CV_8UC4`, `BGRA` image. When I tested the function, both `BGRA` and greyscale images produce valid matrices from the mathematical point of view, but if I pass a greyscale image instead of color, it takes way more to calculate. Which makes me think I'm not doing something correctly in one of the two cases.

I read around that when the change in color space is not linear (which I suppose is the case when you go from 4 channels to 1 like in this case), you should normalize the intensity value. Is that correct? Which input should I give to this function?

Another note, the function is called like this in my code:

```
vector<Point2f>imgpts1, imgpts2;

for (vector<DMatch>::const_iterator it = matches.begin(); it!= matches.end(); ++it)
{
  imgpts1.push_back(firstViewFeatures.second[it->queryIdx].pt);
  imgpts2.push_back(secondViewFeatures.second[it->trainIdx].pt);
}

Mat mask;
Mat E = findEssentialMat(imgpts1, imgpts2, [camera focal], [camera principal_point], CV_RANSAC, 0.999, 1, mask);
```

The fact I'm not passing a `Mat`, but a `vector` of `Point2f` instead, seems to create no problems, as it compiles and executes properly.

Is it the case I should store the matches in a `Mat`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. A `std::vector<cv::Pointf2f>` cannot make use of the OpenCV `convertTo` function.

I think you really mean that you have a `cv::Mat points1` of type `CV_8UC4`. Note that those are `RxCx4` values (being `R` and `C` the number of rows and columns), and that in a `CV_64F` matrix you will have `RxC` values only. So, you need to be more clear on how you want to transform those values.

You can do `points1.convertTo(points1, CV_64FC4)` to get a `RxCx4` matrix.

**Update:**

Some remarks after you updated the question:

Note that a `vector<cv::Point2f>` is a vector of 2D points that is not associated to any particular color space, they are just coordinates in the image axes. So, they represent the same 2D points in a grey, rgb or hsv image. Then, the execution time of `findEssentialMat` doesn't depend on the image color space. Getting the points may, though.

That said, I think your input for `findEssentialMat` is ok (the function takes care of the vectors and convert them into their internal representation). In this cases, it is very useful to draw the points in your image to debug the code.

Comment: I added more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am no sure do you mean by vector of Point2f in some color space, but if you want to convert vector of points into vector of points of another type you can use any standard C++/STL function like copy(), assign() or insert(). For example:

```
copy(floatPoints.begin(), floatPoints.end(), doublePoints.begin());
```

or

```
doublePoints.insert(doublePoints.end(), floatPoints.begin(), floatPoints.end());
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm wondering with this question. Please see update.